# how to change object property value from watching the same object

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a object that i am sending with a $http post.

```
 parameters = {
             foo: foo,
             bar: bar,
             widget: widget,
             bChanged: "0"
        };
```

the default value of bChanged needs to be "0". when the same functioned is fired I need to change the value to "1" if any of the properties values has changed. I would think a simple angular watch function would work but i cant seem to get this figured out.

Comment: How many properties do you need to watch?

Comment: Where is your watch code?

Comment: I was just trying it with a angular watch. Oldvalue != newvalue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a watch in your code

```
$scope.$watch("parameters", function(oldVal, newVal){
   // Do whatever you want to do here
}, true);
```

It will fire every time if there is any change in any property

Comment: its not doing it. do i need to compare each individual property vs the entore object

Comment: see the true at the end, it indicate deep watch, any change in any property, you will also get old and new value

Comment: Did not know what that did. Thanks